# How to clean up Jenkins job so build stability is not affected

Tags: jenkins

How would someone clean up a Jenkins job such that the build stability rating is reset and not affected by previous builds?  I created a build job and through trial and error, I finally got the job to compile/build correctly.  However, I don't want all the previous test builds to affect the build stability rating.  I tried deleting all the builds and restarting Jenkins but it still says 20 of the last 25 builds failed.  I looked in the $JENKINS_HOME directory (~/.jenkins) and couldn't find anything regarding build stability.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure the job you can tell it how long to keep the logs for - either days or build. Set this to one build to clear it out then reset it back again

[image: Discard old builds]

Comment: thx for your reply.  unfortunately that didn't work.  i deleted every build except the last one but it still remembered that the last 20/25 builds were bad.  grr jenkins.

Comment: did you run the job again?

Comment: there is this http://superuser.com/questions/589528/how-do-i-delete-the-builds-11-to-1717-in-jenkins which has a way using the jenkins-cli as the last comment https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

Comment: thanks for the advice.  i don't know what happened but it's no longer a thunder cloud.  I checked on jenkins this morning and my job has a sun on it saying no recent builds failed.  thanks again!