# How to prevent some builds from affecting the stability of a Jenkins project

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

We're using Jenkins with the Gerrit Trigger plugin so when a changeset is uploaded to Gerrit for review, Jenkins will check if it compiles and post the results.

The workflow happens like this:

1. A changeset is uploaded to Gerrit
2. A gerrit hook notifies Jenkins of the new changeset, giving Jenkins certain information such as the Gerrit changeset ID, patch number, target branch, etc.
3. Jenkins launches a build in the project that is configured to listen to this repository.
4. When the project is finished building, jenkins reports the result back to Gerrit if the build was successful or not, either +1 or -1.  This information is used by the code reviewers in gerrit to help them decide to accept the changeset or not.

Problem:  When these builds fail, the Jenkins project is marked "Failing" or "Unstable".  This isn't exactly accurate, because the changes that caused the failure are not accepted or merged into the repository yet, they are just newly proposed.

One feature of Jenkins is that it will measure the health of a project based on the ratio of successful to failed builds.  If the builds are all working, it will show a "sunshine" symbol but if some are failing then you get a "thundercloud".  How do I configure Jenkins so that these verification builds don't affect the stability rating of the project?  We need the status for the project to show "sunshine" if the commits that are approved from Gerrit and merged into the git repository builds, regardless of the outcome of builds from changes that are not merged (those changes in Gerrit still pending review).  It's ok for the individual build to be red instead of green.

Comment: this is what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697051/how-to-clean-up-jenkins-job-so-build-stability-is-not-affected

Comment: Thanks @HiB but I did see that answer already.  That's a manual process and I need something automatic.

Comment: can you write your question then with more detail - sorry to say but still dont understand what do you need

Answer (score 1):

At $DAYJOB, we handle this by using 2 separate build jobs.  A commit validation job, which posts +1/-1 on Gerrit changes and which we don't care about build stability.  And a build stability/regression job, which runs builds that have already been merged where we do care about stability.  We ignore the status color for the commit validation job.

I'm not aware of any way to get the Jenkins plugin to give a -1/+1 vote but always show a status of green.  It uses that status when determining what score to give.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this will work for sure.  I am looking for some way to flag a build as "not significant" for the purposes of calculating project stability.  Our workspaces are many gigs and duplicating them is costly.